# How to create an array for another table details using name in select using mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have saved all product name in the product table. after that im saving the
product multiple details in product_details table. now i need to create a json
like this json given below.

product_table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rice |
| 2 | milk |

product_details_table

| id | brand_name | company_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IGLU | AER432 |
| 2 | IGLU | AER432 |

```sql
select *, array(
            select * 
            from product_details ) as product_details
from product
```

i want to create a json like this format in laravel

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "rice",
        "product_details":[
                            {
                                "brand_name":"IGLU",
                                "company_id":"AER432"
                           },
                           {
                                "brand_name":"IGLU",
                                "company_id":"AER432"
                           },
                           {
                                "brand_name":"IGLU",
                                "company_id":"AER432"
                           }    
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "milk",
        "product_details":[
                            {
                                "brand_name":"IGLU",
                                "company_id":"AER432"
                           },
                           {
                                "brand_name":"IGLU",
                                "company_id":"AER432"
                           },
                           {
                                "brand_name":"IGLU",
                                "company_id":"AER432"
                           }    
        ]
    },
    
   
]
```

Comment: You should make relation between these tables(1 to 1) and after that use eager loading in your query.

Comment: you are saying Eloquent in laravel ..but this quary is sample json  ... i need a keyword to create an array for another scenario.. just need the keyword how i can create product_details array shown in this json.. for better understanding i create this json.. and thanks for help

Comment: This way is not good. But if you want, you can create an object and put these query's result in it.